# nodejs axios socket hangup on certain POST and PUT requests

Tags: node.js, axios

I have an app that acts like a middleware between my frontend and backend. It injects authorization based on cookies.

Some PUT and POST requests fail with socket hang up error.

```
axios.create({
        timeout: 10000,
        httpsAgent:  new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true })
    })
```

The strange thing is that not all requests fail.

There is one server where PUT and POST requests consistently fail with Axios but not with node-fetch and postman.

I tried to decide if it is a specific header or the payload itself that causes the issue but I found nothing.

I tried to use axios 0.27.2, 1.1.3. node 12, 14, 16. None of the combinations worked.

I traced the call and found that the request hangs at

```
      req.end(data);
```

axios/axios/blob/v1.x/lib/adapters/http.js#L586

Comment: I have experienced ECONNRESET errors when making many concurrent https connections (perhaps because my number of local ports was exceeded). I could prevent these errors by using a `new https.Agent({keepAlive: true, maxSockets: 10})`. Does this work for you?

Comment: Nope, this is a single request that fails. But the loing aslo uses post and there is a different server for another update and that one works as well.

Answer (score 0):

your request must be for a port other than the one you are running on test cases in the same environment.

Ex:

- Backend -> Port 5268
- Frontend -> Port 63259

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to edit  your answer to improve formatting; you can apply  **Frontend -> Port 63259**, or _Frontend -> Port 63259_, or `Frontend -> Port 63259` and do some paragraphs.